# What is wrong with this Taylor series $f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{t \arctan^2 t}{1+t^2}\ dt $

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

We have
$$f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{t \arctan^2 t}{1+t^2}\ dt $$
and I'm trying to evaluate the first terms of its Taylor series at zero. [Wolfram output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1%2F3%20i%20tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29%5E3%20-%20tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29%5E2%20log%28-%282%20i%29%2F%28-i%20%2B%20x%29%29%20-%20i%20tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29%20Li_2%28%28i%20%2B%20x%29%2F%28-i%20%2B%20x%29%29%20-%201%2F2%20Li_3%28%28i%20%2B%20x%29%2F%28-i%20%2B%20x%29%29%20-%20%283%20%CE%B6%283%29%29%2F8&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D) shows:
$$ f(x)= \frac{3\zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{x^4}{4}+o(x^4)$$
I can't see how to get that $\zeta(3)$ factor, since the first derivative is
$$f'(x)=\frac{x \arctan^2 x}{1+x^2}$$
which is $0$ when $x=0$. And so is the second derivative
$$f''(x)=\arctan x\frac{2x+\arctan x-x^2\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2} $$
The term of $\frac{3\zeta(3)}{8}$ should be the linear term of the expansion right? But it is $0$ so how can this be?

Comment: $f(x)= \frac{3\zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{x^4}{4}+o(x^4)$ is obviously wrong around zero.

Comment: I see it wrong, since $f(0)=0$.

Comment: saw it here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Barctan%2C2%5Dx%2C1%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to evaluate the first terms of its Taylor series at zero, which should be
> $$ f(x)= \frac{3\zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{x^4}{4}+o(x^4)$$

Why do you think this is the right form? If you plug in $x=0$, you get

$$ f(0)= \frac{3\zeta(3)}{8}$$

But contradicts with the fact

$$f(0)=\int_0^0\frac{t \arctan^2 t}{1+t^2}\ dt=0 $$

So your Taylor series is wrong.

Regarding the [Wolfram output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1%2F3%20i%20tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29%5E3%20-%20tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29%5E2%20log%28-%282%20i%29%2F%28-i%20%2B%20x%29%29%20-%20i%20tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29%20Li_2%28%28i%20%2B%20x%29%2F%28-i%20%2B%20x%29%29%20-%201%2F2%20Li_3%28%28i%20%2B%20x%29%2F%28-i%20%2B%20x%29%29%20-%20%283%20%CE%B6%283%29%29%2F8&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D), note at the bottom it has the polylog term,

$$-\frac{1}2\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{i+x}{-i+x}\right)$$

If you set $x=0$, it becomes

$$-\frac{1}2\text{Li}_3(-1)=\frac{3}8\zeta(3)$$

which cancels your constant term.

Comment: Saw it here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Barctan%2C2%5Dx%2C1%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: @Zima You should add such context to your question. But that's asking only for an indefinite integral, so it gives _an_ antiderivative, not necessarily the $\int_0^x$ (zero-at-zero) antiderivative.

Comment: But it has the polylog term, $-\frac{1}2\text{Li}_3(-1)=\frac{3}8\zeta(3)$ which cancels your constant term @Zima

Comment: I am referring to the series at the bottom of the page

Comment: @J.G I see now why the constant matter, thank you.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the complex representation of the arctangent function
$$\tan^{-1}(t)=\frac{i}{2} \log{\left ( \frac{i+t}{i-t}\right )}$$ the antiderivative is not too difficult.

Expanding the result around $x=0$

$$f(x)=\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{5 x^6}{18}+\frac{49 x^8}{180}-\frac{409
   x^{10}}{1575}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$ which you could have obtained directly by the Taylor expansion of the integrand
$$\frac{t}{1+t^2} \big[\tan ^{-1}(t)\big]^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\, t^{2n+1}$$
the first coefficients being
$$\left\{1,-\frac{5}{3},\frac{98}{45},-\frac{818}{315},\frac{517}{1
   75},-\frac{169819}{51975}\right\}$$